# Was my comment on my answer on this post removed, and why?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Was my comment on my answer on this question removed, and why?

[What is this early 3D platformer?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24942/what-is-this-early-3d-platformer)

It was an unpleasant shock to see the site silently misrepresenting me as rude by not acknowledging their thanks when I was sure I had. If it was removed, I'd like to have been told about it. [context, it was a reply to a comment which two hours later was deleted also.] Surely, SE can spare the bandwidth for 'you're welcome', especially when the answer's been accepted and there's not going to be much further discovery to disrupt.

If it's policy, then a) I don't like it, I want it changed, and b) I want to be told when I've violated it.

(Alternatively if it was just a site glitch I will sheepishly throw up my hands of course.)

Answer (score 9):

Your comment was removed. It's policy to remove comments once they've served their purpose. On many sites, answers get the following comments:

- Thanks for this answer. It's really great!
- You're welcome! Happy to help.

When these are flagged as No Longer Needed, they're removed. To reduce workload on moderators, comments like these can be removed just from user flags, without a moderator's intervention. (This rule is designed for big sites like Stack Overflow.)

Usually, moderators delete these conversations at the same time. However, in this instance, the "thanks" comment was:

> This is definitely the right game! ❤

The algorithm (designed for Stack Overflow) has no idea that this is a thank-you comment; it's talking about a game, and doesn't even *say* "thank you". Whereas your reply:

> No problem, you're welcome

was – save for the emoji – a classic. So your comment was deleted when it was flagged, but mm201's remained until I deleted it 4 hours, 46 minutes and 56 seconds later.